# How can I have the addressing section of Case email open by default?

Tags: email, case, page-layout, casefeed

When I send an email from the Case Feed, it opens with the addressing section collapsed and defaults to the Contact email address. I would like the section to be visible by default so the user doesn't forget to check who they are sending the email to, as in our situation it is NOT always to the Case contact. We use @mention for SF users, but some employees don't have a login, and we need to email them. So it's critical the support user sees the TO field at all times.

How is this doable? Google hasn't helped so far...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you put a picture for better understanding

Comment: Havew edited Santanu

Comment: find my answer ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is Salesforce Out-of-box functionality where `Email` in Feed based layout will be displaying like that because in the Feed View settings of the Page Layout `Allow Collapsible Email Header` option in by default selected.

[image: Feed view navigation]

> De-select this option.

[image: Allow Collapsible Email Header]

Email section will display like this:

[image: Email in Feed layout]

> By the way, in the Console app it will always be **non-collapsible**, even if "Allow Collapsible Email Header" option is selected

Answer (score 0):

In our org we use console app and it is not always non-collapsible. We have to deselect the checkbox to make it non-collapsible.